# Generic table loading EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

There are two tables: `Teachers` and `Students` both of them can be derived from a base class `Human`.

May load a `DbSet<Human>` from `Teacher` and `Student` class? and do a generic function, e.g. generic inserting

pseudo code:

```
class Student : Human
{
   //
   //
   //
   DbSet<Human> GenericLoading(...)
   {
       //
   }
}
```

usage of generic DbSet:

```
void Insert<T>(DbSet<T> entities, string name, int age) where T: new(),Human
{
   entities.Add(new T{ Name = name, Age = age });
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for [Table-Per-Concrete-Type (TPC) inheritance](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines).
Derive the two entities from the same base class `Human` and configure each entity class use its own table, then declare a `DbSet<Human>` in your `DbContext`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [IQueryable.Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb351755(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a union Query, if it is about loading the data:

```
var teacherQuery = db.Teacher.Select(e => new Person {...})
var studentQuery = db.Student.Select(e => new Person {...})
var combinedQuery = teacherQuery.Concat(studentQuery);
```

I am not sure how you could do an insert, if you don`t know the exact properties.